# Quel temps utiliser dans une phrase qui contient « ne plus » et « depuis » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

Il est écrit dans la sous-section intitulée "Translating *since*" --> "Depuis: *since* in a negative sentence" dans *Advanced French Grammar* (p. 191) de V. Mazet :

> In a negative sentence with **ne ... plus** (no longer), the main verb (outside the **depuis** clause) stays in the present. Exemple fourni : Elle **ne travaille plus** depuis sa grossesse.

Si je ne mémorise que cette règle, je l'oublierai sous peu. Par conséquent, je voudrais savoir pourquoi le présent simple est utilisé et pas un autre temps ?

Cette citation de Nicolas Philibert Adelon dans [Dictionnaire de médecine, ou, répertoire général des sciences médicales](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=MPaOU8dSEjkC&pg=PA200&dq=%22ne%20figurait%20plus%20depuis%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=cjypUvORDKaSiQekg4GwAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ne%20figurait%20plus%20depuis%22&f=false) est-elle un contre-exemple :

> Parmi les auteurs modernes, les uns, comme Lorry, ont décrit l'épinyctide en avouant qu'ils ne l'avaient pas vue. Les autres ont reproduit brièvement la description de Celse, mais toujours sans rapporter le moindre fait à l'appui. Enfin, relégué dans les vocabulaires, le mot épinyctide **ne figurait plus depuis** nombre d'années dans les Traités de maladies de la peau, quand M Alibert, qui n'en avait fait aucune mention dans ses premiers ouvrages, l'admit plus récemment comme septième genre des *Dermatoses eczémateuses*.

Comment: Cette règle me semble bancale. En français, il existe deux types de temps lors d'un récit. Le classique passé : (imparfait/passé simple et assimilés), et le présent (et assimilés). Dans les deux cas, tu pourras mettre du « ne plus », ou alors, c'est privé la plupart des romans d'un « ne plus ». Personnellement, je n'ai aucun soucis à dire : « D'ici cinq jours, elle ne travaillera plus ici. ».

Comment: Des temps de l'indicatif, seul le passé simple et le passe antérieur me semble impossible à utiliser dans la structure _Elle ne [travailler] plus depuis sa grossesse_.  (Je n'ai pas d'exemples pour lesquels le futur antérieur n'est pas substituable au futur simple en gardant le même sens et en semblant de meilleur style).  Si on supprime la nécessité d'un _depuis_, tous les temps me semblent convenir et apporter quelque chose.

Comment: M’est avis qu’il manque du contexte à ton extrait. De quoi traite le chapitre et la section dans lesquels il est situé ?

Comment: @Édouard: J'ai ajouté plus de renseignements. Prière de me faire savoir si vous en désirez plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tout dépend du contexte, si l'action qui se déroule "***depuis***" (l'évènement qui l'a déclenché) est finie ou pas. Le verbe sera au présent si l'action a encore cours. Sinon il sera au passé.

> Elle ne travaille plus depuis sa grossesse.

La grossesse de cette femme a eu pour conséquence de la faire arrêter de travailler. En mettant le verbe au présent, il est sous-entendu qu'elle continue à ne plus travailler. Si elle avait repris le travail, la phrase aurait été au passé : "*elle ne travaillait plus depuis sa grossesse [et a repris le travail après son congès maternité].*".

> Enfin, relégué dans les vocabulaires, le mot épinyctide ne figurait
>   plus depuis nombre d'années dans les Traités de maladies de la peau,
>   quand M Alibert [...] l'admit plus récemment comme septième genre des
>   Dermatoses eczémateuses.

Le mot "*épinyctide*" a été relégué des vocabulaires (pour des raisons qui nous échappent) et le mot disparut des traités dans les traités avec cette relégation. Un jour un certain M. Alibert a levé ce "bannissement" via l'admission (comme septième genre des Dermatoses eczémateuses). Par conséquent M. Alibert a mis fin cette non-figuration du mot "*épinyctide*" dans les traités. Le bannissement étant terminé il est donc on ne peut plus normal qu'il soit au passé.

Dans le cas d'un verbe au passé, il est à noter que l'on utilise les formes imparfaites (imparfait ou bien plus-que-parfait). Ceci est justifié par le fait que l'action qui se passait "***depuis***" ce qui l'a déclenché a duré dans le temps. Du coup il est important de savoir si ce qui a mis fin à ce qui se passait "depuis" est terminé ou pas. Dans l'exemple de la question l'admission comme septième genre est encore valide dans le temps. Ce qui a mis fin à ce qui se passait "depuis" n'est pas encore terminé donc le verbe passé est à l'imparfait. Mais si ce qui a mis fin à ce qui se passait "depuis" est terminé, on se trouve alors dans le cas d'une antériorité et c'est donc le plus-que-parfait qui est utilisé, comme dans l'exemple suivant :

> L'équipe n'avait plus gagné par trois buts d'écart depuis le départ de son meilleur attaquant.

L'équipe a gagné par trois buts d'écart pour la dernière fois, le meilleur attaquant est parti, l'équipe n'a alors plus gagné aussi largement jusqu'au jour où elle l'a fait.

Pour résumer, on a donc :

- Le **présent** si l'action qui se passe depuis n'est pas finie.
- L'**imparfait** si l'action qui se passait depuis est finie et si ce qui y a mis fin n'est pas fini.
- Le **plus-que-parfait** si l'action qui se passait depuis est finie et si ce qui y a mis fin est également fini.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. Je souhaite que je puisse voter maintes fois à l'appui de votre réponse gentiment globale et merveilleuse ! Prière de me faire savoir de ma révision ; je ne voudrais que trier des phrases plus longues en les mettant entre parenthèses.

Comment: @LePressentiment: C'est lisible tel quel. Ajouter des crochets n'est pas standard et rend justement le texte illisible.